# Python: how to run a single unittest method from within the unittest.main() statement?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Assuming a unittest module such as:

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase)

    def testA(self):
        pass

    def testB(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

How can I change the unittest.main() statement to run only testB?

Comment: Notice that this question is -not- about specifying which test method to run via command line.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs outline that `defaulTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) can be specified:

```
unittest.main(
  module='__main__', 
  defaultTest=None, 
  argv=None, 
  testRunner=None, 
  testLoader=unittest.defaultTestLoader, 
  exit=True, 
  verbosity=1, 
  failfast=None, 
  catchbreak=None, 
  buffer=None, 
  warnings=None
)
```

> The defaultTest argument is either the name of a single test or an
>   iterable of test names to run if no test names are specified via argv.
>   If not specified or None and no test names are provided via argv, all
>   tests found in module are run.

Comment: You might want to add some newlines to your code so that the parameters are in a column rather than in a long line needing scrolling.

More specific to the answer, I am glad you listed the official documentation as it will provide additional information. 

I guess what I was looking for (but didn't communicate it) was some examples, as I had read the docs and it just wasn't clear to me that defaultTest needed strings in the form "classname.methodname" - hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter defaultTest does the job, as it accepts a list of `"<classname>.<methodname>"` strings, i.e.:

```
unittest.main(defaultTest=["MyTests.testB",])
```

As dm03514 rightly points out, this is described in the official documentation of [unittest.main()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main), albeit without a specific usage example.

Comment: Hi, please expand on *why* this code answers the question. Code snippets without context are not considered good answers.